# HTML tabs not showing in webform (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, webforms

I'm using html-tab view in which tabs are hidden by CSS and will be visible only by a JavaScript function. But it doesn't work in a webform of ASP.NET.

It just shows at once and fades away within half a second.

I copied from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs_fade).

Code is:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MASTER/MASTER.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CREATE_USER.aspx.cs" Inherits="CRM_CAPSULE.MASTER.WebForm2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">


<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
    animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

/* Fade in tabs */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
</style>



</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


<h3>Fade in Tabs</h3>

<div id="tabs" class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="tabs">

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

</div>

<script>


    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }



</script>

</asp:Content
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS and JavaScript codes work correctly.

A

```html
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
    animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

/* Fade in tabs */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
</style>







<h3>Fade in Tabs</h3>

<div id="tabs" class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="tabs">

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

</div>

<script>


    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }

</script>


</script>
```

It's may there is issue with asp:Content ...

Check page from browser and be sure that you CSS and JS codes are in correct place on page.

Comment: The problem was.....Every thing was right, but whenever I hit any tab, The page again refresh and comes to the initial stage where no tab were showing their content. So, to solve this. I just write "return false;" where the javascript function was calling and page will not refresh itself.

Comment: <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'User'); return false;">Create User</button> <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Customer'); return false;">Create Customer</button> <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'M_User'); return false;">Modify Users</button> <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'M_Customer'); return false;">Modify Customer</button> –

Comment: Thanx for your help brother :)

Answer (score 0):

First, replace your second id="tabs" with class=" tab", because you can not use duplicate id. And try this script.

```
var tabArea = ".tab .tablinks",
    tabContent = '.tabcontent';
$(tabArea).add(tabContent).each(function () {
    $(this).siblings(':first-child').addClass('active');
});
$(tabArea).on('click', function(){
    $(this).each(function(){
        var tabIndex = $(this).index();
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent('.tab').next(".tab")
            .find(tabContent).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).parent('.tab').next(".tab")
            .find(tabContent).eq(tabIndex).addClass('active');
    })
});
```

Also Add following CSS

```
.tabcontent.active { 
  display: block;
}
```

You can refer this codepen demo: https://codepen.io/kravisingh/pen/xrQqNO

Comment: You can find your working code here [https://jsfiddle.net/3q8dn1of/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/3q8dn1of/3/)

Comment: Thanx brother for help.

Comment: The problem was.....Every thing was right, but whenever I hit any tab, The page again refresh and comes to the initial stage where no tab were showing their content. So, to solve this. I just write "return false;" where 
 the javascript function was calling and page will not refresh itself.

Comment: <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'User'); return false;">Create User</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Customer'); return false;">Create Customer</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'M_User'); return false;">Modify Users</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'M_Customer'); return false;">Modify Customer</button>

Comment: if any problem occurs in this code again then I will try your code. Thanx for your help brother :)